# Remove function names when compile C++ project

Tags: c++, function, static-analysis

I want to make my app harder for static analysis and remove function names from .exe file when compile in release mode, how can i do it?

And could you please advise technics to make my app harder for static analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: good code doesn't have to hide

Comment: in general, executables don't contain function names. can you specify which platform/tools do you use? function names are typically included as a part of debug info, which usually can be avoided by using proper arguments to compiler/linker

Answer (score 2):

Use the `strip` program. Make malformed executable files that the OS accepts but disassemblers don't. Etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you heml  me, how to do this in Visual Studio 2010? Thanks!

Comment: @Breakdown I don't know, I've never pogrammed on Windows. I'm sure, however, that a quick Google search will lead you to the Windows ABI specification which can be of great use for this purpose.